# What is the best way to implement Token economics in Substrate based blockchain?

Tags: substrate-node-template, token

I want to implement Token economics in my Substrate based chain. Can someone please guide what is the best way to implement it? Which pallets should I use?

Is there any example?

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Can you elaborate more on what you're looking to do?